# My PHP file is not parsing correctly

Tags: php, parsing, url-rewriting

I am having a strange issue that I have never encountered in the past 10 years, please help.

I am working on a very simple site for a client, they have a shared host LAMP stack, I am using an .htaccess file like this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1
```

So I can access pages like `domain.com/contact` and it will go to `domain.com/?p=contact` pretty straight forward, however on the index page, `domain.com` it will not parse the PHP correctly, if I view source I can see my actually PHP code un-parsed on this page, all the other pages work except for my index page, any ideas why this would happen?

It worked fine on my localhost

---

Update

I can access `domain.com/index` and `domain.com/index.php` and they work fine, it is just when I access `domain.com` that it does not parse correctly

Comment: Quite strange..Is it working without rule in `.htaccess` ?

Comment: You probably need to look into your apache.conf file.

Comment: "It worked fine on my localhost" - how many times have I heard that...

Comment: Does the index file work without the rewrite rules?

Comment: Confirm that removing the rewrite does not change anything

Comment: A small hint - you do not need both lines here. Just RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the server's setup is messing with DirectoryIndex option - it tries to find the "closest" file, but does not run php engine for it. Yes, it sounds "weird", but try to add this string to .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

ps: and another thing I wrote in comments - one RewriteRule is enough: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1`

Comment: thank you that did the trick, I wasted at least an hour thanks!